# Django csrf unwanted token rotation

Tags: python, django, csrf

Using Django 1.97 the following view:

```
@staff_member_required
def admin_news_categories_json(request):
    nodes_list = []
    for node in NewsCategory.objects.filter(parent__isnull = True):
    n = {
        'id' : node.id
        'title' : node.title,
    }
    nodes_list.append(n)
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(nodes_list))
```

is causing the CSFR token to be change (rotated) everytime it is loaded.

It is called via ajax from an admin form so is causing the form submission to fail through CSFR token mismatch.

If I remove @staff_member_required decorator the CSFR remains unchanged! I have another view with the csfr_exempt decorator and that view also changes the csfr token.

Is this a known bug or a feature? :)

Comment: What makes you thing that the view is causing the CSRF token to be rotated?

Comment: When you see the CSRF token change, what is the result of this view?  Does it return JSON, or does it redirect to the login page?

Comment: If I open a seperate tab with a form (and a csrf token), everytime I reload the page the token stays the same. If I reload the json view and then reload the form the token has changed.

Comment: Json view always returns json as expected, no login. I also went one step further and commented out token rotation in /django/contrib/auth/__init__.py login function... but still the csrf token is being changed by json view.